# Run word macro on keypress in document

Tags: vba, ms-word

What I am trying to create is a writing assistant for MS word that gives me advice during writing. In order for that, I need to check whether the letter or number keys on a keyboard are pressed and if so, run a macro that shows the assistant popup and do the background work.

The problem is that I can't get the keypress detection to work. I tried multiple things like the two examples below but they don't give me the desired effect.

```
Private Sub document_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
If KeyAscii > -1 Then
    MsgBox ("You Pressed a key")
End If
End Sub

Private Sub document_open()
    'This line may differ depending on whether you are running this from a document template or an add-in.
    Application.CustomizationContext = ThisDocument.AttachedTemplate
    ' Create the keybinding.
    KeyBindings.Add KeyCode:=BuildKeyCode(wdKeySpacebar), KeyCategory:=wdKeyCategoryMacro, Command:="MyMacro"
End Sub
```

The first one is not working at all and the seconds overwrites the keybinding which makes the spacebar in this example useless. With the second example, I also have to assign a binding for each character.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: If you must use the spacebar to call a macro and don't wish to lose the space character then your macro should insert the space character at the insertion point when it is called.

Comment: @Freeflow the spacebar was just an example. That example also has the disadvantage that I have to assign a binding for each character on the keyboard.

Comment: In that case I think what you want to do is near impossible in VBA.

Comment: @Freeflow What part is impossible? If I can detect a specific keypress, why is it then near impossible to detect multiple keys. In javascript you can, for example, say if keys with the code 30 to 40 are pressed then...

Comment: You need to detect each character (which isn't clear in your original post) but you don't want to assign a binding for each character.  Thus you need to intercept the stream of key presses coming into Word.  AFAIK there is no event to do that for Word itself, only when you are in a form or control.  If it were easy I would find lots of solutions when I google.  The fact I don't find these solutions is telling. I don't think I can help further.

Comment: Word's built-in ability is limited to keybindings, so yes, it's necessary to define a binding for each character that should be "trapped". Note that you could do this once, in a template, then create the documents from that template or possibly load it as an add-in. The only other possibility is to use the Windows API to create "keyboard hooks". This is not something I've ever done "seriously"; I have heard it's not terribly reliable in Word (Office, generally) due to how the application interfaces handle things, so YMMV.

Comment: Some possibly useful links from a Google search: https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/languages/VBA/Win-API/examples/key-press, http://www.cpearson.com/excel/keytest.aspx

Comment: @CindyMeister I found a workaround that works perfectly. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via links that were shared in the post, I came across a program called AutoHotKey. After some research, I set up a system where AutoHotkey does the detecting part and then calls the macro in word. I use the following hotkey script:

```
Keybinding for a-x before this
y::
    send y
    StartLabel("a")
    return
z::
    send z
    StartLabel("a")
    return
Space::
    send {Space}
    StartLabel("a")
    return
Backspace::
    send {Backspace}
    StartLabel("a")
    return
^Backspace::
    send ^{Backspace} 
    StartLabel("a")
    return  

StartLabel(x)
{
    word:=ComObjActive("word.application")
    word.run( "Writeass" )  <-- macro name. No need to define the module first
}
```

This script calls the macro every time one of de defined keys is pressed.

With a simple bat file I can start and close the script (to make sure it does not run in the background when wordt is not open). 
Bat code to start the script:

```
start C:\path to Autohotkey script\WriteAssistant.ahk
```

Bat code to end the script (killing the autoHotKey process)

```
taskkill /im AutoHotkey.exe
```

I use the following vba script to start and close the hotkeyscript from a word macro (in my case I made a button in the ribbonbar to start the macro and the first thing it does is start the autoHotKey script):

```
Path = "C:\path\start.bat"
Shell Path
```

And best of all, I didn't notice any speed loss.

Comment: Wow - this looks interesting, can you expand on this example and perhaps share your experience about getting this set up in MS Word? +1

Comment: Hey Vinc - I disappeared down a AHK rabbit hole yesterday and wow, ... it looks fantastic. Really glad to hear no noticeable speed loss - thanks

Comment: For anyone following along... this is an interesting read: https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=8978

Answer (score 1):

Since your question implies that you are doing this for yourself and not trying to deploy this macro to others, you can simply assign a keyboard shortcut to the macro from Word Options and you don't have to write custom keyboard trapping VBA to do this.

1. From Word's File tab select Options
2. Click Customize Ribbon
3. Click Keyboard shortcuts: Customize...
4. Select Macros from the All Commands Categories list
5. Locate your custom Macro and Assign a custom keyboard sequence

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this does not work for me because a shortcut has to to be for example ctrl + a and I only need 'a'  or one of the other letters of the alphabet.

Comment: @Vinc199789, if you are looking for a two key sequence I suggest Alt+a because the Ctrl key is primarily used by the OS and/or the Office applications.

Comment: I found a solution, see my answer